# Styled tooltip for html map/area

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-events

Is there a simple way to make a styled tooltip for an `<area>` in a `<map>` ? By default the browser seem to render the area text into a yellow text box. But I've got cases where the text should be formatted.

I've been trying with Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips and popover but they're always positioned at the top left of the window. At 0,0.

**UPDATE - screenshot and code**

Telling to add popovers to the area elements of the piechart. Each `<area>` corresponds to one section of the pie chart.

```
$('area').popover({content:"I'm a cut off popover" ,trigger:'hover'});
```

I'd like to have the popover appear next to the hovered-on section.

I'm aware of comparable questions related to `<area>` in Stack Overflow. My case however is different in the sense that I don't know upfront the size and positions of the sections. So I can't generate a custom style to set the *top* and *left* properties.

[image: Popover is put into the left upper corner]

The same happens for regular tooltips. They're put into the left upper corner. But I'd rather go for popovers because I need formatted content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fugly as hell, but something like this? http://klinsj.net/turneplan.php?index=-35

Comment: Look guys, if I could solve this problem on own, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. So even if this looks like a dummy question, it isn't to me. I'm a newbie for this kind of stuff. Downvoting is not exactly going to help, would it ? :-)

Comment: The calendar tooltip would indeed by a vast improvement over the default behavior. Thanks ! :-) Did you use a library ?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the title attribute which does this yellowish browser tooltip.

For a **custom** tooltip, you must use a **custom** solution (javascript based, obviously). I suggest you use a library (like jQuery) and find a tooltip plugin which does what you want like [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)

#### Update

For the css issue with the bootstrap tooltip, it looks like there is a position issue. Please provide more code so we can figure out what's goin' on.

Comment: Can't add code because it's a pile of junk generated by a server-side web framework. Would a screenshot help ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this is a bug in Bootstrap
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5000